# two foreach loops in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this razor view:

```
@using Order.Models
@model CategoriesViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="panel-group">                   
        @foreach (var p in Model.Categories)
        {
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@p.ID.ToString()">
       @p.Name
        </a>                     
                  </h4>
              </div>
               <div id="@p.ID.ToString()" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                   <div class="panel-body">  
          @foreach (var m in p.Items)                           
                       {
                          //put items data here
                       }                      
                   </div>
    </div>
              </div>     
        }        
    </div>
}
```

Which uses this viewmodel:

```
namespace Order.Models
{
    public class CategoriesViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RestCategories> Categories;
        public List<List<RestItem>> Items;
    }
}
```

And the controller action is:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Categories()
        {
            List<List<RestItem>> ItemsForCategory = new List<List<RestItem>>();
            API OneApi = new API();
            IEnumerable<RestCategories> itemsResult = API.GetCategoryResults("test", "test");
            if (itemsResult.Count() > 0)
            {                
                foreach (RestCategories cat in itemsResult)
                {
                    ItemsForCategory.Add(OneApi.GetItemsForCategory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"], cat.ID.ToString()));
                }
            }

            CategoriesViewModel modelCat = new CategoriesViewModel
            {
                Categories = itemsResult          
                .OrderBy(i=>i.Order),
                Items = ItemsForCategory                             
            };
            return View(modelCat);
        }
```

Now, I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this but I want to show categories and within those categories I want to show the items in that category. I can get all the items in a list and as you can see in the view I'm trying to loop through the Items collection but I'm not able to get the Items property from the model. I also tried this approach

> @foreach (var m in Model.Items.Where(n=>n.CategoryId = p.ID))

but still nothing.

Comment: I don't think you need list<list on your items.  try taking off a layer.  When I have nested loops I use the bottom foreach that you show.  Are you seeing categories but not items?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to see categories but not items. The method I'm using is returning List of items, which then is put in a new list for each category id, that's why I'm using double lists. @MattBodily Thx for helping me

Comment: if you just return a list<items> with all of the items in one list the second foreach will parse them out for you.  You won't need to put them into a second list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than have two enumerables in the model you could just have the category, and it's associated items, and then pass a list of those into the view.

So your model would look like:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public RestCategories Category;
    public List<RestItem> Items;
}
```

Your Controller would do something like:

```
IEnumerable<RestCategories> categories = API.GetCategoryResults("test", "test");
var categoryModels = categories.OrderBy(c => c.Order)
                               .Select(c => new CategoryViewModel
                                       {
                                           Category = c,
                                           Items = OneApi.GetItemsForCategory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"], cat.ID.ToString())
                                       })
                               .ToList();
return View(categoryModels);
```

Your view would have a model type of `IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>` rather than `CategoriesViewModel`, and would do something like this:

```
<div class="panel-group">                   
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@m.Category.ID.ToString()">
                        @m.Category.Name
                    </a>                     
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@m.Category.ID.ToString()" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">  
                    @foreach (var i in m.Items)                           
                    {
                        //put items data here
                    }                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    }        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a value that probably does not exist:

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Items.Where(n=>n.CategoryId = p.ID))
```

**n.CategoryId** does not exist because n is referencing an item of the Items list (which is also a list).

Do you mean maybe:

```
 @foreach (var m in Model.Items.Where(n=>n.SOMETHING = p.ID))
```

I write SOMETHING because you have a list of list and maybe it should be:

```
public List<RestItem> Items;
```

and then n will have the RestItem and you would be able to access its properties.

If what you need is a list for each category, then what you should have is:

```
namespace Order.Models
{
    public class CategoriesViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RestCategories> Categories;
        public List<ListRestItem> Items;
    }
    public class ListRestItem
    {
       public int CategoryId;
       public List<RestItem> Items;

    }
```

And with this your previous code should work.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to my first answer would be to leave the model, and view type, as you currently have it.  In the controller action you want to make sure that the two enumerables have the same ordering with respect to category.  You can then combine them in the view like this:

```
<div class="panel-group">                   
    @foreach (var m in Model.Categories.Zip(Model.Items, (c, i) => new { Category = c, Items = I }))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@m.Category.ID.ToString()">
                        @m.Category.Name
                    </a>                     
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@m.Category.ID.ToString()" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">  
                    @foreach (var i in m.Items)                           
                    {
                        //put items data here
                    }                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    }        
</div>
```